# Is 012 a three-digits number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, definition

Over a discussion with a friend, he mentioned a math problem:

> How many five-digit numbers can you make out of 0, 1, 2

<sup>(the wording could be better because it is not clear whether it has to be made from all three digits, or if only from a subset but that's not the point of my question)</sup>

We ended up disagreeing about whether `000012` is a **five**-digit number, or just a **two**-digit one.

**My question**: I there a **formal** definition/consensus about how leading zeroes are to be treated, i.e. whether they can, could, must or must not be part of a number.

My stance (that I am not particularly attached to) was that the problem explicitly differentiates "digits" from "number" and hints about positioning (and combinatorics).

Comment: $012$ is a three-digit string.  However, it is a two-digit number.

Comment: Usually , leading zeros are not allowed for a positive integer. Reasonable , since we could otherwise not determine the number of digits.

Comment: If $00012$ is a five-digit number, then $\frac{1}{2}$ being $0,5000000000000000000$ is a number with 19 decimals :-)

Comment: 012 is now a syntax error in Python. Long ago, the leading 0 was used to denote an octal representation.

Answer (score 0):

(A) All numbers [[ Eg $0$ & $1$ & $2.3$ & $0.45$ ]] can be (must be) written with leading & trailing Zeros [[ Eg $.....0000.00000....$ & $...00001.0000.....$ & $....0000002.30000000.....$ & $0000000000.4500000000.....$ ]] then all numbers (must) have Same infinite number of Digits.
It is not useful to count the number of Digits in this Case.

(B) With that in view , it is better to not count the leading & trailing Zeros , unless the Zeros are necessary to indicate the Decimal Point.
Hence we say $012$ (leading Zero) has $2$ Digits , while $102$ (Zero in middle) & $120$ (trailing Zero necessary to indicate Decimal Point) have $3$ Digits.
This is the formal Definition of counting Digits , which goes by terms like Precision , Accuracy , [Significant Digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) , Etc.

Comment: The question didn't mentioned decimals anywhere.

Comment: So you mean Decimals do not exist ? The Answer must be complete , @An_Elephant , hence we must mention Decimals ! If you wish , you can ignore the Decimal Parts in (A) , in which Case , my Answer in (B) still stands ! I am not sure what the Objection is ?

Comment: No , I only said that OP was looking for natural numbers.

Comment: I gave Answer for Natural Numbers as well as rational numbers. Check this [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures ] , where it says "An exact number has an infinite number of significant figures. .... If the number of apples in a bag is 4 (exact number), then this number is 4.0000..." , which is a long way to State that $4=4.00000000$ , though in my Answer , readers can leave out (A) & consider (B). **Here OP wants formal Definition , which involves Decimals.**

Comment: Okay. I    get it.